# Java - Type Mismatch: Cannot Convert From Element type String[] to List<String>

Tags: java

I'm unfamiliar with getters and setters (and basically just Java) but I have to use them for this assignment, so if I did anything wrong with those please tell me.

The more important issue is the error that I am getting on my method. The word for word instructions from my assignment for the particular method I'm working on are:

> Your processData() method should take all the record data from your ArrayList and add the data into each of your instance fields via your setters.

But I keep getting an error that says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String[] to List

On the line that says "`for (List<String> rowData: content)`" on the word content.

Thank you very much for any help you can give me.

My code so far:

```
public abstract class Client {

  String file = "bank-Detail.csv";
  ArrayList<String[]> bank = new ArrayList<>();
  static Client o[] = new Client[12];

  public Client(String file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  private String ID;
  private String Age;
  private String Sex;
  private String Region;
  private String Income;
  private String Married;
  private String Children;
  private String Car;
  private String Save_Act;
  private String Current_Act;
  private String Mortgage;
  private String Pep;

  public List<String[]> readData() throws IOException {
    //initialize variable
    int count = 0;
    //name file
    String file = "bank-Detail.txt";

    //make array list
    List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();

    //trycatch for exceptions
    try {
      //file reader
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      //string to add lines to
      String line = "";
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content.add(line.split(","));
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    processData(content);
    return content;
  }

  public String getID() {
    return ID;
  }

  public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
  }

  public String getAge() {
    return Age;
  }

  public void setAge(String age) {
    this.Age = age;
  }

  public String getSex() {
    return Sex;
  }

  public void setSex(String sex) {
    Sex = sex;
  }

  public String getRegion() {
    return Region;
  }

  public void setRegion(String region) {
    Region = region;
  }

  public String getIncome() {
    return Income;
  }

  public void setIncome(String income) {
    Income = income;
  }

  public String getMarried() {
    return Married;
  }

  public void setMarried(String married) {
    Married = married;
  }

  public String getChildren() {
    return Children;
  }

  public void setChildren(String children) {
    Children = children;
  }

  public String getCar() {
    return Car;
  }

  public void setCar(String car) {
    Car = car;
  }

  public String getSave_Act() {
    return Save_Act;
  }

  public void setSave_Act(String save_Act) {
    Save_Act = save_Act;
  }

  public String getCurrent_Act() {
    return Current_Act;
  }

  public void setCurrent_Act(String current_Act) {
    this.Current_Act = current_Act;
  }

  public String getMortgage() {
    return Mortgage;
  }

  public void setMortgage(String mortgage) {
    this.Mortgage = mortgage;
  }

  public String getPep() {
    return Pep;
  }

  public void setPep(String pep) {
    Pep = pep;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[ID = " + ", age=";

    /// ect....
  }

  public void processData(List<String[]> content) {

    int index = 0;
    for (List<String> rowData : content) {
      //initialize array of objects
      //o[index] = new Client();

      //use setters to populate your array of objects
      o[index].setID(rowData.get(0));
      o[index].setAge(rowData.get(1));
      o[index].setRegion(rowData.get(3));
      o[index].setSex(rowData.get(2));
      o[index].setIncome(rowData.get(4));
      o[index].setMarried(rowData.get(5));
      o[index].setChildren(rowData.get(6));
      o[index].setCar(rowData.get(7));
      o[index].setSave_Act(rowData.get(8));
      o[index].setCurrent_Act(rowData.get(9));
      o[index].setMortgage(rowData.get(10));
      o[index].setPep(rowData.get(11));

      System.out.println(rowData);

      index++;
    }
  }

  public void printData() {
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `processData` method change `for (List<String> rowData: content){` to `for (String[] rowData: content){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `processData` method. The type of `content` is `List<String[]>`. So when you try to loop this list, each element is a `String array`, not `List`. Also, since each element in  your list is a String array, you can access the elements of each of the String Array elements of the list by using the normal array square brackets, instead of `get` method of List. Try the following fix:

```
public void processData(List<String[]> content) {

    int index=0;
    for (String[] rowData: content){
        //initialize array of objects   
        //o[index] = new Client();

        //use setters to populate your array of objects
        o[index].setID(rowData[0]);
        o[index].setAge(rowData[1]);
        o[index].setRegion(rowData[3]);
        o[index].setSex(rowData[2]);
        o[index].setIncome(rowData[4]);
        o[index].setMarried(rowData[5]);
        o[index].setChildren(rowData[6]);
        o[index].setCar(rowData[7]);
        o[index].setSave_Act(rowData[8]);
        o[index].setCurrent_Act(rowData[9]);
        o[index].setMortgage(rowData[10]);
        o[index].setPep(rowData[11]);

        System.out.println(rowData);

        index++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error hints at... `content` is a `List<String[]>`, so it contains `String[]` elements, not `List<String>` elements.

---

If your end goal is a list of `Client` objects, just make the method `List<Client> readData()` instead.

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    //file reader
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    //string to add lines to
    String line = "";
    Client c = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        c = new Client();
        String[] rowData = line.split(",");
        c.setID(rowData.get(0));
        ...

        clients.add(c);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}  

return clients;
```

Comment: The problem is with his foreach loop in processData method

Comment: I am aware. And that's what I said in the first line of my answer